# installing repository for com.android.support.recyclerview-v7 for Android Studio error

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner in android studio and I try to use a recyclerView. When I try to add `compile 'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'` to my gradle file, I get the error:

```
 failed to resolve com.android.support.receyclerview-v7v7:21.0.+.

It proposes me to install repository and sync project. when I click it, i get this error:
SDK Path C:\User\userName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1
loading SDK information
ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository' warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install. Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
install failed, please check your network connection and try again. You may continue with creating your project, but it will not compile correctly without the missing components.
```

I mention that I'm using sdk 23.0.0 on a windows system, and when installing android studio for the first time I got an error message that concern proxy (that i unfortunately skipped)!!

Any idea to solve this problem ??!!!

Comment: since you are using sdk 23, have you tried `com.android.support.recyclerview-v7:23.0.+` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, run the SDK Manager and check if your support libraries repository is updated.

Then open your `build.gradle` (not the top level file) and add:

```
dependencies{

    //....
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Pay attention. You report in your question a typo in your library (compile 'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7:21.0.+')

Using the v23 you have to compile with API23.

Of course you can use a "old" version using:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.1.3'
```