# Why am I still getting installing repository for RecyclerView error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I am following a guide on using the [Recycler View](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156), I having trouble with the part of declaring the dependency and installing the RecyclerView into Android Studio.

I added the RecyclerView to my xml file and declared the dependency in build.gradle(below)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ryde.chris.ryde"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.supportrecyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

I rebuilt the app and tried installing the Recycler View repo. When installing, I ran into the same exact issue that this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252543/installing-repository-for-com-android-support-recyclerview-v7-for-android-studio) did.

I took a look at the answer on that thread. I chose to use RecyclerView v 23.0.0 and made sure that I compiled with api version 23 (compileSdkVersion 23 in build.gradle). Using the AVD manager, I also made sure that my support library for api version 23 was installed and updated[image]

Does anyone know why I am still getting this issue? Internet is working fine (this to be specific)[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
compile 'com.android.supportrecyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```

Comment: You must be careful!

Answer (score 1):

Use the new version:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```